# What is the best way to send notification after a field change?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, notification, push-notification

I want to send a notification to the user every time a specific field (SecondName__c) is changed

What would be the best way to do this? Trigger or flow?

Answer (score 1):

Flow is probably the easiest, you can create a channel in setup under custom notifications and use the send custom notification action in your flow.